# Android Facebook API and ShareLinkContent

Tags: android, facebook

for my Android App Game I have implemented a Button that allows the user to share the result of a game.

I have integrated the Facebook SDK, so all classes are known to my project. 
The manifest contains the following tags:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider16..."
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:exported="true"/>
```

When I run the app I can share the result of the game with the code below.

```
public void onShareResult(View view){
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    final ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);

    shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "error");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "cancel");
        }
    });


    if (shareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {

        ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
               .setContentTitle("Game Result Highscore")
               .setContentDescription("My new highscore is " + sum.getText() + "!!")
               .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.ginkoboy.flashcards"))

               //.setImageUrl(Uri.parse("android.resource://de.ginkoboy.flashcards/" + R.drawable.logo_flashcards_pro))
               .setImageUrl(Uri.parse("http://bagpiper-andy.de/bilder/dudelsack%20app.png"))
               .build();

        shareDialog.show(linkContent);
    }


}
```

However there are some things I do not understand.

- The shared link looks different from what I see in the dialog before I post.
- Images seem to have been available via internet. i.e. It is not possible to set an image of a resource from my project.

Furthermore I have some trouble understanding what Facebook is requiring.

This is how Facebook displays my posting:

[image: This is how Facebook displays my posting:]

And this is how my App seem to post the content

[image: And this is how my App seem to post the content]

So the question is: Where is my title and description gone???

Best regards

Oliver

Comment: You can look this example with facebook sdk share https://github.com/oliguo/android-facebook

Comment: Hey @mustafasevgi, 
thanks for this information. However it seems that this example is only about accessing content from facebook not creating content.

Answer (score 8):

So, I have found out the reason why my title and description was not visible in facebook.

First of all thanks @mustafasevgi but your solution refers to SDK 3.5.x where I tried to use SDK 4.0

Coming back to the solution...

I have found out that I have set up my content Url to my App inside the Google Play Store. If you set up a content Url outside of Google Play Store the title and description will not be overwritten.

Comment: What do you mean by "content Url to my App inside the Google Play Store"?

Comment: @Satyam:   I set the content title, the content description and the content url      `ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
               .setContentTitle("Game Result Highscore")
               .setContentDescription("My new highscore is " + sum.getText() + "!!")
               .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.ginkoboy.flashcards"))`

Comment: the above snippet in the reply is same as in the question right ? I do not find any the answer to this issue. Could you please help me

Comment: Could you please throw some light on " If you set up a content Url outside of Google Play Store"

Comment: If you set an URL that targets to "https://play.google.com/store/apps..." the title and the description will be taken directly from the targeted page. 
If you set an URL that targets to any url outside of the google play store the title and description, that you have entered in your ShareLinkContent.Builder() is considered.
So this can not be solved by changing the code but rather change the URL.

Answer (score 2):

you can use setQuote("Any Description String") method of ShareContent.Builder to set the quote to display for your link.
Something like that

```
if (shareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {

    ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
           .setQuote("My new highscore is " + sum.getText() + "!!")
          .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.ginkoboy.flashcards"))
           .build();

    shareDialog.show(linkContent);
}
```

P.S. setTitle , setDescription and setImageUrl methods are deprecated now in Latest Facebook SDK

Answer (score 0):

facebook sdk 3.X with use this code.You can use WebDialog.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookOperationCanceledException;
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.WebDialog;
import com.facebook.widget.WebDialog.OnCompleteListener;

public class FaceShare extends Activity {

   String link = "", id = "", pic = "", title = "";

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      Intent i = getIntent();
      Bundle b = i.getExtras();

      // link = b.getString("link");
      // id = b.getString("id");
      // pic = b.getString("pic");
      // title = b.getString("title");

      try {

         // start Facebook Login
         Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
               if (session.isOpened()) {

                  // make request to the /me API
                  Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                     @Override
                     public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {

                     }

                     // callback after Graph API response with user object
                  }).executeAsync();

                  publishFeedDialog(title, "title", "caption", link, pic);
               }
            }

            // callback when session changes state
         });
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
         Log.e("FACE", e.toString());
         finish();
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
   }

   private void publishFeedDialog(String name, String caption, String description, String link, String urlPicture) {
      Bundle params = new Bundle();
      // params.putString("name", name);
      // params.putString("caption", caption);
      // params.putString("description", description);
      // params.putString("link", link);
      // params.putString("picture", urlPicture);
      params.putString("name", "name");
      params.putString("caption", "caption");
      params.putString("description", "description");
      params.putString("link", "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/1b/2b/19/1b2b19519b1b3439f783181026d9872b.jpg");
      params.putString("picture", "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/1b/2b/19/1b2b19519b1b3439f783181026d9872b.jpg");

      Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

      WebDialog feedDialog = (new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(FaceShare.this, session, params)).setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
         public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException error) {
            if (error == null) {
               // When the story is posted, echo the success
               // and the post Id.
               final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
               if (postId != null) {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shared.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  finish();
               }
               else {
                  finish();
               }
            }
            else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
               finish();
            }
            else {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                              "error occured, try again",
                              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               finish();
            }
         }

      })
                                                                                               .build();
      feedDialog.show();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used WebDialog system but I have this message:

Cannot use SessionLoginBehavior SSO_WITH_FALLBACK when com.facebook.LoginActivity is not declared as an activity in AndroidManifest.xml

does anyone know why?

Comment: Have you declared this Activity in your AndroidManifest?

Something like


`<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"...`

Comment: According to [Reference of LoginActivity](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/class/LoginActivity/) you need to declare LoginActivity in your manifest:
    `<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:label="@string/app_name" />`