# Facebook Android: share image AND link

Tags: android, facebook

I need to share a picture AND a link using Facebook.

It seems it's not possible.

Is there a definitive answer?

Comment: Facebook app? Facebook SDK? *It seems it's not possible.* how do you figure? What have you tried? Any problems you've run into? Your question is not very clear, and a tad too broad.

Comment: @Lisa SO isn't a "**give me the code site**". What have you tried? Where's your code ? I wonder how a question like this survived enough time to get a bounty. I'm going to flag this question to a moderator.

Answer (score 7):

Quoting from [developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#links):

> **Links**
>
> When people share links from your app to Facebook, it includes
>   attributes that show up in the post:
>
> - a **contentURL**, the link to be shared
> - a **contentTitle** that represents the title of the content in the link
> - a **imageURL**, the URL of thumbnail image that will appear on the post
> - a **contentDescription** of the content, usually 2-4 sentences

If you want to display also the image you should use [setImageUrl(@Nullable final Uri imageUrl)](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/share/model/ShareLinkContent.java#L139-L142):

```
ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(contentUrl))
                .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(imageUrl))
                .build();
```

The result will be something like this:

[image]

Comment: One question regarding this -  Can i do any sort of redirection from HelloFBSample link to some external site (Having a problem with Sorry, Prijemni app hasn't been approved for display in App Center.)

Comment: HI, How can I send the image along with the link? the image URL is not working now. Is there any other way to add an image to the link.

Answer (score 2):

Yes It's possible,Please check this link.
[Sharing on Android https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please edit your answer to correct this, then flag your post to request un-deletion

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is like this?

[image]

If so, it is possible by using Facebook SDK. This is sample code.

```
Bitmap image = ...
SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
        .setBitmap(image)
        .build();
SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
        .addPhoto(photo)
        .build();
```

This link may help you. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it like described in the [Facebook SDK Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#links)?

```
ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                        .setContentTitle("Title")
                        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://www.yoururl.com"))
                        .setImageUrl(Uri.parse("http://www.yourserver.com/image.jpg"))
                        .build();

shareDialog.show(linkContent);
```

Comment: #at time show the only image or Url both are not displayed in one post

Answer (score 0):

If you want it for links you go this official documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android 
There you will find share link content part:

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.facebook.com"))
        .build();
```

Also there you will find the share picture part:

```
Bitmap image = ...
SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
        .setBitmap(image)
        .build();
SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
        .addPhoto(photo)
        .build();
```

Here you can find an example:
http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-share-an-image-on-facebook-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

@Lisa Anne

To share content such as **`text,images,link`** we need to use the [ShareLinkContent class](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/ShareLinkContent). We can set the url, title, description to be shared using the **`setContentUrl(), setContentTitle(), setContentDescription()`** methods.

### How to Call

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder().build();
Your_Dialog_Obj.show(content);
```

Its Class Short Example

```
public final class ShareLinkContent
extends ShareContent<ShareLinkContent, ShareLinkContent.Builder> {
private final String contentDescription;
private final String contentTitle;
private final Uri imageUrl;

private ShareLinkContent(final Builder builder) {
    super(builder);
    this.contentDescription = builder.contentDescription;
    this.contentTitle = builder.contentTitle;
    this.imageUrl = builder.imageUrl;
}

ShareLinkContent(final Parcel in) {
    super(in);
    this.contentDescription = in.readString();
    this.contentTitle = in.readString();
    this.imageUrl = in.readParcelable(Uri.class.getClassLoader());
}

/**
 * The description of the link.  If not specified, this field is automatically populated by
 * information scraped from the link, typically the title of the page.
 * @return The description of the link.
 */
public String getContentDescription() {
    return this.contentDescription;
}
```

Courtesy goes to [developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android) .
   So you can understand passing `imageURL` ,`contentDescription` easily .

***Demo Example***

```
ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(contentUrl))
            .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(imageUrl))
            .build();
```

> If your app share links to the iTunes or Google Play stores, we do not
>   post any images or descriptions that you specify in the share. Instead
>   we post some app information we scrape from the app store directly
>   with the Webcrawler. This may not include images. To preview a link
>   share to iTunes or Google Play, enter your URL into the URL Debugger.

Build your share content for photos into the [SharePhotoContent](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/SharePhotoContent) model. For a list of all attributes, see [SharePhotoContent](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/SharePhotoContent) reference.

```
Bitmap image = ...
SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
        .setBitmap(image)
        .build();
SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
        .addPhoto(photo)
        .build();
```

> [Android Facebook API and ShareLinkContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29554085/android-facebook-api-and-sharelinkcontent)

***Git Demo For Understanding Purpose.***

1. [FacebookImageShareIntent](https://github.com/b099l3/FacebookImageShareIntent)