# setImageUrl in android facebook sdk 4.14.0 is not working when hashTag is included

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-share

Here i am trying to share the page with hashtag.

```
 ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                                .setContentTitle("Hello Facebook content tilte")
                                .setContentDescription("this is content description")
                                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/Fishing-303261736469954/?fref=ts"))
                                .setImageUrl(Uri.parse("http://www.villathena.com/images/nearby/thumbs/le-bus-bleu-private-tours.jpg"))  //Uri.parse("https://d3kvf6cfq06287.cloudfront.net/influencer/image2_1469508676.jpg"))
                                .setShareHashtag(new ShareHashtag.Builder().setHashtag(influencer.hashtag_name).build())
                                .build();
                        shareDialog.show(linkContent);
```

Problem am facing here is,

-> After posting, I am not getting the image in `setImageUrl()` in post, instead i am getting the shared page image.

Its for working fine(what i except) without `setShareHashTag()`,but my requirement is to include the hashtag.

Here i have attached the screenshots,

[image: Screenshot 1]

After posting,

[image: Screenshot 2]

I don't know what is missing,if any one know the answer please help !!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer this may be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29554085/android-facebook-api-and-sharelinkcontent

Comment: It might have to do with that you are sharing a Facebook page, and Facebook is limiting what parameters you can set at run-time, at least for the web Feed dialog, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog#params I would expect this to be the case in other situations/using other sharing mechanisms as well. [...]

Comment: [...] That the behavior currently is different depending on whether you are using a hashtag or not, might be a bug. But for the future, I think you can expect Facebook to limit this for all sharing methods, because it simply was abused to much in the past (people posting links to pages with completely misleading title/description/image.)